# how to order records in stable query in TDengine?

Tags: tdengine

I created a stable and a few sub-tables, then I used below SQL to list all records, but the result is not ordered by ts column. any way to do it?

select * from stable1

Answer (score 0):

You can use order by to order your retrieved data.

```
select * from table order by ts;
```

[image: example pic]

For more infomation about `order by` you can refer [search `order by`](https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/taos-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `order by` in a TDengine query sql statement, for example to sort a stable by `ts` column with `desc`ending order.

```sql
select * from log.dnodes_info order by ts desc
```